# only the last setInterval run

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code

```
function RefreshElastic() {
    Elastic.refresh();
}

function ShowTime() {
    var Sekarang = new Date();
    var Waktu = Sekarang.getDate() + "/" + 
                Sekarang.getMonth() + " - " + 
                Sekarang.getHours() + ":" + 
                Sekarang.getMinutes();

    $("#jam").html(Waktu);
    Elastic.refresh();
}

var IntervalElastic = setInterval(function () {
    RefreshElastic();
}, 500);

var IntervalTime = setInterval(function () {
    ShowTime();
}, 1000 * 30);
```

I want to have 2 intervals, each has a function to call.
The RefreshElastic called only twice.
The ShowTime always called every 30 seconds.

Why is that?

Additional note:
I changed the millis for RefreshElastic to a larger value, like 5000. And RefreshElastic never called.

Comment: The code looks OK - check the console for errors.

Comment: This truly simple fiddle works http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ZVgHu/; the error must be somewhere else, the function is fired? What is _Elastic.Refresh_ ?

Comment: @James, I am using Chrome's developer view. I get no errors.

Comment: @Edward Elastic.Refresh is a function come from a css framework "elastic". It recalculates the width of divs.

Comment: @Edward yes I have and it logs the events as I described.

Comment: @fasisi you must provide a relevant jsfiddle without it is difficult to check

Comment: @Edward I tried some modification on jsfiddle but I forgot the url. But I have found a way to get the RefreshElastic get called.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the issue, but ok

Comment: to all, I found a way to get the RefreshElastic get called. But it is spesific to Grails, so I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007994/first-javascript-function-call-never-executed). If you have an answer, you may post it there.