# first javascript function call never executed

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a Grails view with script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /* the first setInterval */
    setInterval(
      function()
      {
        console.log("Test...");
      },
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      function()
      {
        console.log("Test... (2)");
      },
      5000
    );

    GetContent(1);
    GetContent(2);
    GetContent(3);
    GetContent(4);

    setInterval(
      Test0,
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      Test2,
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      ShowTime,
      1000 * 10
    );

    setInterval(
      Test3,
      1000 * 9
    );

    setInterval(
      Test1,
      1000 * 8
    );

</script>
```

I wonder, why the first setInterval never executed?
Somehow, the first javascript function call never executed. The function call shows up in the html (view source), but it never executed.

If I copy the first setInterval and paste it right underneath the first one, so I have 2 identical function call, only one of them get executed.

The console only write "Test..." once each 5000 milliseconds.

Is it a bug in Grails?

Comment: More information is needed on the Grail functions that you're calling. I've created a fiddle with just your first two calls and they work: http://jsfiddle.net/s4yBM/ (see console)

Comment: the Grails function I call that using the view is this: render(view:"view-display").

Comment: @RamniqueSingh do you know any reference that say about the rules or restrictions on making javascript function call in Grails layout or view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is simply to bind those javascript function calls to document's ready event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(
  function()
  {

    /* the first setInterval */
    setInterval(
      function()
      {
        console.log("Test...");
      },
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      function()
      {
        console.log("Test... (2)");
      },
      5000
    );

    GetContent(1);
    GetContent(2);
    GetContent(3);
    GetContent(4);

    setInterval(
      Test0,
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      Test2,
      5000
    );

    setInterval(
      ShowTime,
      1000 * 10
    );

    setInterval(
      Test3,
      1000 * 9
    );

    setInterval(
      Test1,
      1000 * 8
    );

  };

</script>
```

Now, everything executed as expected.